# Is this possible to retrieve public informations from facebook without access token?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-access-token

I've got a simple question, but can't find out any real solution/answer.

Is that possible to retrieve Public informations about someone's facebook profile, just by typing its firstname and lastname?

Eg. I'm typing for John Doe, and some "API" return to me his first/last name, gender, age range, localisation…

Since now, I only could get `Invalid OAuth access token` when using application's access_token, and `This action can be taken only on the current user and the param 'id' (if any) must be the current session user.` if I directly query /{the-user-id}/?fields=xxxxxx

Comment: No that is not possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From far I've read, that's not possible (especially now that columbia analytica stolen data !)

(also pointed out by @WizKid)